# Limit imagemagick resource consumption

Tags: memory, imagemagick

Imagemagick's `convert -list resource` lists the resource limits for imagemagick processes:

```
  File       Area     Memory        Map       Disk   Thread  Throttle       Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   768   33.584GB  15.639GiB  31.277GiB  unlimited        8         0  unlimited
```

In particular, I am converting a large number of images and my computer freezes up. Memory usage gets visibly high in `top`. Which limit is appropriate for solving this?

What is the difference between "area", "memory", and "map" resources? When I run `convert 'images/*.jpg' -limit area 1GiB -limit memory 1GiB -limit map 1GiB ...`, `top` shows me that it is using more than `1GiB` and my computer freezes.

Comment: please read ImageMagick documentation fully, as there mentioned how you can limit resources though

Comment: @αғsнιη As I state in the question, the memory limits [documented](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit) do not seem to help.

Comment: From the link you quoted, I would guess, it's either `area` or `memory`. Why don't you just try it yourself?

Comment: Please review the question to see what I tried.

Comment: Did you try other limit settings like `-limit file` as well?

Comment: @dessert Gave up and switched to `find`

Comment: @Hatshepsut While that's more of a workaround than a solution it nevertheless answers the question, so please add an answer below explaining what you did.